# Using require js with angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I'm trying to use require js and angular js together. Referred to someone guides by googling:

- http://marcoslin.github.io/angularAMD/#/home
- http://www.sitepoint.com/using-requirejs-angularjs-applications/

Both guides seem to use angular, and angular-route and angular-amd, but I thought they were for other complicated purposes, so I only used "angular js" (so there is no `shim` in require.config()).

My `main.js` looks like this;

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery      : 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min',
        'angular'   : 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min',
        'class'     : 'class',
        'utility'   : '../utility/utility',
    },

    deps: ['main1']
});
```

where `deps: ['main1']` is the file to load right after require is defined as the first guide uses.

But I'm keep getting this error:

[Error: $injector:modulerr](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=UpdateApp&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:nomod%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.0%2F$injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DUpdateApp%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.0%2Fangular.min.js:6:416%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.0%2Fangular.min.js:25:136%0A%20%20%20%20at%20b%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.0%2Fangular.min.js:24:188)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.0%2Fangular.min.js:24:431%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.0%2Fangular.min.js:39:287%0A%20%20%20%20at%20n%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.0%2Fangular.min.js:7:355)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.0%2Fangular.min.js:39:135)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20fb%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.0%2Fangular.min.js:43:164)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Ac.c%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.0%2Fangular.min.js:20:449)

('UpdateApp' is the name of the app that I'm using in my project.)

And the webpage says that I get the error when I've forgotten to include the file with the defined module.

Not using `deps: ['main1']` but using `require(['angular'], function(){}` and logging out `angular.module('myApp',[])` logs Object nicely though. ... It seems like `require(['angular'], function(angular)` does not work but `require(['angular'], function()` works for me, and guides don't seem to tell me whether I should do the latter or the former.

I thought it would be as simple as adding angular js in `paths`, and loading it with `require()` or `define()` will work, but it's not...

How do I use Require JS and Angular JS as simple as just using them together to print "hello world"?

Comment: @SatejS Oops. I did not know the page included that. I thought it was a simple error page that explains $injector:modulerr. `UpdateApp` is `myApp` in my question. It's just name of the app that I'll be using in my project. Anyways, my code works fine if I don't use require JS.

Answer (score 1):

Looking into your code, I can see that you clearly mis-understood about the concept of using requireJS and angular together. Either of the links you found are make by expert JS developers. Where both tried to combine angular and requireJS as simple as it could. So you need to accept the fact that it is complicated.

**=>** This is why I will not try to help you with some code. Because it will took lots of time and it will related with many topic which will not likely fit into a single question and answer on stackoverflow.

> How do I use Require JS and Angular JS as simple as just using them together to print "hello world"?

At first I want to repeat it. This is nothing like simple work. For `requireJS` you need to at least have advanced knowledge about what called AMD and able to imagine how things happen asynchronusly when `requireJS` trying to load an JS library.

Secondly, common knowledge about `angular` module/service injeaction. Since both requireJS and angular can do some sort of module/service injection you need to know about the difference between these two.

Third, the initial stage of your webapp. Since both requireJS and angular need to be initialled to run properly. So this will also the requirement.

### Sum up

You will NOT able to understand both in a day or two. It will take time. But fortunately I have a couple of suggestions for you.

- Research some about how requireJS and angular load their depenencies.
- Go for `angularAMD` get the project seed. Set it up, run it, play with it.
- Improve your knowledge about the initial state of both.
- ...
- Profit!

**P.S.** just FYI. An year ago, I started with requireJS and angular. And I got hitted up with a big wall of knowleges, just like you. And these are what I have tried to understand them. Take your time, it is not like using `jquery` which can learn in a day or two. Even for some JS expert it took months just for them to confident about angular (not counting combine it with requireJS). Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your **P.S.** I thought I was a dumb dumb for not understanding AngularJS and combining it with requireJS. You encouraged me a lot. Thank you. I guess I'm gonna study angularAMD.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your main1.js you must be use require(['angular'], function(){} to start your application.

Comment: Haven't tried that because in this [link](http://marcoslin.github.io/angularAMD/#/home), it uses `define` instead of `require`.

Comment: If you define the application, it won't execute the function. You have to require it for it to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Require JS will give you a package dependency manager, concatenator/uglifier, javascript file loader, and an injector. Require JS injectors are used for injecting classes versus Angular, which is used to inject instances.

The big advantage is that RequireJS is going to speed up your application by managing your load and runtime dependencies. It's useful for big SPA's.

You can set up your file structure by defining all of your dependencies using "define". For functions to execute, you will need to use "require".

Here is a helpful video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4yulGISBF8w&index=1&list=PLgVbnDyASc1qDAam3Fe0f-u6u9MYL6pC8